# jQuery Parser Error Long JSON text

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, parse-error

**fixed;**

I'm using a simple jQuery to download text off a server, datatype json.

```
$.get('http://169.254.100.5/ajax.php',{action:'p',i:'{$data['id']}'},function(data)
{
     $.each(data.responses, function(i,response)
     {
       alert(response.longtext)
     }
}
```

When response.longtext is short (less than 1000 chars like "hello world") i have no problem and the script behaves normally.

When response.longtext is long (like a paragraph of lorem ipsum) i get a parsererror.

I did some experimenting and rewrote it using $.ajax(...) and dropped the $.each method and I still get a parser error.

```
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
{
    alert("err: "  + textStatus);
}
```

Comment: post the complete error and sample response

Comment: `'{$data['id']}'` is also an obvious syntax error.

Comment: '{$data['id']}' is a php element

Answer (score 0):

How do you print the data in the server? Maybe you didn't escape charcters correctly. Do you use `json_encode` in php?

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance the response is not encoded properly. Did you try just doing eval() on the responseText?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, my bad, it was the `\t` and `\n` in the lorem ipsum that caused my error.

I wasn't using `json_encode` because I'm generating the json on the fly with a `$stmt->fetch()` loop. Just slashed out the problematic characters and it's fine.